# Facebook API to read bookmarked items

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook recently added a new feature which allows bookmarking interesting links for reading later. Saved links are available in „Save” tab.

Is there any Facebook API (e.g. Graph API) for retrieving these saved items ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No such API feature exists. 
If this will change it will be announced here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Answer (score 14):

The documentation  of the API endpoint to access Facebook "Saved Links" used to be available at the following link:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/action-type/save.saves/

However, Facebook removed the support for it around February/March 2016.

Answer edited on Apr, 15 2016. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: Strange, though that link used to work, it seems like that functionality has been removed. Also there is no mention in the changelog about it either.

Comment: Yup, it just disappeared ([screenshot](http://take.ms/HDCLk) from the Internet Archive) and the example code returns an empty array now.

Comment: Thanks for the comments John and @mu3. I edited the answer.