# Facebook api supports saved items?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Does the Facebook api allow you to pull the information from saved articles on Facebook to download and read it in another app?

Comment: Currently this is not supported IMHO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook API to read bookmarked items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25511271/facebook-api-to-read-bookmarked-items)

Answer (score 4):

No, not anymore. It used to be accessible until [early 2016](https://web.archive.org/web/20160117180758/https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/action-type/save.saves/).

See also: [Facebook API to read bookmarked items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25511271/facebook-api-to-read-bookmarked-items).

As for a manual solution, see [Scrape your Facebook saved links](https://medium.com/cod3/how-to-export-your-facebook-saved-links-to-pocket-c34828dd5f8e) ( scroll to the bottom of the list, paste a js to console → it generates a text list of urls). 
I'd guess one ccould automate that further, via a headless browser instance.

Answer (score 3):

As of now **they don't have an api for saved items**. Read this techcrunch [post](http://techcrunch.com/2014/07/21/facebook-save-feature/) for more details .

> I’ve asked Facebook whether websites and Page admins will get
>   analytics on how often they’re Saved, which could help refine their
>   content and promotion strategies, and better understand what to share
>   on Facebook. It tells me “**Not at this time**.” There are currently **no
>   plans for an API or external Save button** that developers could use to
>   let people add to their Saved list from outside of Facebook. You also
>   can’t natively export from Save to other read-it-later apps, which
>   would be nice.